What should we do about questions asking about Market data or Data sources in General?
There seem to be alot of questions in the form of "Where can I find ..... type of data".
On stack overflow, questions like this are usually community wiki as there usually isn't one definitive answer.
Here we don't seem to follow that same philosophy, which is fine, but I think its worth considering if we should.
Also since there are such a large number of questions like this, should we create a tag specifically for questions about sources of data to make it easier for people to search for them?
Something like data-source? 
Or should we go a different route, like having a sticky topic at the top that is community wiki liking to all the data source questions?
Thoughts??

The tag will certainly help, I'll look at that later today. The rest I find harder to judge, CW discourages effort so I'm leaning against that. Personally I don't find the data questions all that interesting so I'm hesitant to make it sticky. OTOH, less data questions would be an improvement (for me). I'm curious what the rest of the community has to say.

Behold: http://quant.stackexchange.com/tags/data-source/info, this tag can use some love :)

The data market is starting to change rapidly since Yahoo API was depreciated last year. There are new data players in the market and a library for "where can I find..." would be helpful.
